# Is there any benefit in using Predicate<T> over building a query manually?

Tags: c#, linq, predicate

Say I want to filter a customer list by some criteria pulled from the user. For example, say they can enter text into any of a number of textboxes, and search on that (eg search by customer name, country, etc).

I can do something like the following...

```
IEnumerable<Customer> matches = customers; // start off with the full list

if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(customerName)) {
  matches = matches.Where(c => c.Name.Contains(customerName));
}

if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(customerCountry)) {
    matches = matches.Where(c => c.Country.Contains(customerCountry));
}
```

This does the job, and is pretty readable.

On the other hand, I can do the following...

```
List<Predicate<Customer>> predicates = new List<Predicate<Customer>>{
  c => string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(customerName) || c.Name.Contains(customerName),
  c => string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(customerCountry) || c.Country.Contains(customerCountry)
};

IEnumerable<Customer> matches = numbers.Where(n => predicates.All(p => p(n)))
```

As noted in one of the answers, the above code redundantly checks string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(customerName) in every case. Rather than spend time rewriting the code for a side-issue, please ignore that point.

Is there any benefit to one over the other? If not, when would I ever use predicates?

Comment: I disagree with your assertion "...those not familiar with predicates (most programmers in my experience)".  I think that any programmer worth his salt should have no problem understanding and/or working with predicates.

Comment: If you use `Func<Customer, bool>` in your list in the second snippet then you don't need to create an entirely new method just to convert it into one later on.

Comment: @roryap Or at least any not familiar with the concepts should be capable of figuring them out on their own easily enough.

Comment: Furthermore, `Predicate` is just a predefined delegate that is provided by the .NET class library, and everyone should know how to use delegates just fine.

Comment: @roryap I said "in my experience." I don't claim to know what the dev community at large knows, but amongst the programmers on my team (and others I've worked with in recent years), most of them don't have time to dive deep into stuff like this, and just aren't familiar with things like predicates. I like to try and learn, but most people I know don't put in the time.

Comment: @Servy Can you elaborate on what you meant by using Func<Customer, bool> please

Comment: @AvrohomYisroel -- Please don't take this the wrong way, but I think you (and your colleagues, if, in fact, that is the case) are doing yourself, your employer, and your clients a disservice by simply "skimming the surface" and avoiding the powerful tools available to you.  Delegates are a fundamental concept in .NET and other languages and not at all complicated once you get used to them.

Comment: One difference between good programmers and great programmers is the desire to learn at all costs, to improve your craft.  Simply getting the job done is not enough.

Comment: @roryap Don't worry, I didn't take it the wrong way, but I was commenting on what I see around me. However, I did point out that *I* do try to learn all the time. This has caused problems when I've used some bit of code that the CTO didn't like (probably because he wasn't comfortable with it). I agree that we should learn as much as possible, and use the best tools for the job. I just don't see that happening around me. All of which is tangential to the actual question, which was is there any benefit to predicates over building the query manually.

Comment: @AvrohomYisroel What is there to elaborate on?  It's the delegate that you should have used, but didn't, and that is forcing you to jump through unnecessary hoops later on as a result.

Comment: @Servy "What is there to elaborate on?" I don't understand how you are suggesting I use the Func, that's what there is to elaborate on. An example would have been more clear.

Comment: All of which still doesn't answer my original question. Not only that, but I have two votes to close the question. Why? It seemed like a perfectly reasonable question to me, but has been railroaded by a discussion on whether or not devs should learn the trade properly - something with which I completely agree, and have said so a couple of times.

Comment: @AvrohomYisroel You change the type, just like I said.  You shouldn't need to see code to replace one type with another in a specified location.  Clearly you need to just learn the fundamentals of delegates.  You should probably pick up an intro C# book and read up on the topic.

Comment: @AvrohomYisroel -- For what it's worth, I gave you a +1.

Comment: I've removed the comment that seems to have side-tracked people off the actual question. Please just look at the two approaches and tell me if there is any technical benefit to one over the other.

Comment: @Servy I understand C# delegates thank you, it was your comment that I didn't understand. I am perfectly capable of replacing one type for another, but don't see what benefit it gives me. You said "then you don't need to create an entirely new method just to convert it into one later on" which I didn't understand. If I replace Predicate<Customer> with Func<Customer, bool> then the code works exactly the same way. What have I gained?

Comment: @AvrohomYisroel You then don't need to convert the `Predicate` into a `Func` when providing it to the `All` method, as it expects a `Func<T, bool>`.  You no longer need to create a lambda just to convert the delegate to another type with the same signature, just like I said in my first comment.

Answer (score 1):

At least, this one:

```
c => string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(customerName) || c.Name.Contains(customerName)
```

assumes, that `string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(customerName)` will be checked for every list item, while first one checks this only once.

Comment: Can you explain this a bit more? Won't it be checked in every case?

Comment: He's right, your predicate version redundantly checks `string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(customerName)` a thousand times, even though it doesn't depend on `c`.  A better version would add `c => c.Name.Contains(customerName)` to the list of predicates only when `customerName` is set.

Comment: Ah, didn't spot that. Good catch.

Answer (score 0):

Although it might seem intimidating to you its actually not.Imagine you work in an IT company where your boss asks you to create an application where you can search all of the employees based on any of the available criteria in the corporate database.Well thats not hard You have an Employees table and you just need to search the fields in there.So you create an application and wire up your textboxes to supply your value and based on that you query the database.Your boss is happy but still not satisified now he wants your application to query based on multiple columns -- in any order and possibly using them all. So you allow the user to pick, from a check box list, any of the fields that will be included in the query, and to specify the criteria.Solving this problem without LINQ and the PredicateBuilder basically requires the writing of a query variation for every possible combination of columns.

The [PredicateBuilder](http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/predicatebuilder.aspx) just makes it easy to combine an undetermined number of criterias. So when you are writing code to data access layer you might not want to change the whole code instead just alter your predicate builder class.

Comment: `PredicateBuilder` really only exists for dealing with `Expression` objects.  It's not really necessary for dealing with delegates, given that actually invoking them is easy, unlike with expressions.

Answer (score 0):

After playing with this some more, I discovered a major difference between the two, so unless anyone can show me a way to do it, I don't think you can use the predicate approach with Linq2Entities.

I created a new console app, added an EF model connected to the Chinook database, and added the following code...

```
  using (ChinookEntities ctx = new ChinookEntities()) {
    List<Func<Album, bool>> predicates = new List<Func<Album, bool>> {
      a => a.Title.Contains("AC"),
    };
    List<Album> albums = ctx.Albums.Where(c => predicates.All(p => p(c))).ToList();
  }
}
```

When you try to run this, you get the following exception...

*"Unable to create a constant value of type 'System.Func`2[[Chinook.Album, Chinook, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null],[System.Boolean, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]]'. Only primitive types or enumeration types are supported in this context."*

It looks like Linq2Entities just doesn't support this approach - unless someone can show me how to get around this.

Hope this helps someone.